# How to send email in laravel?

Tags: laravel, email, eloquent

I want to send the data of the last order just made by the user

I already have my .env configured

AfterOrder Class: (Class type mail)

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\Order;

class AfterOrder extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    
    public $order;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->Order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        
        return $this->view('mail.after-order');
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Name: {{$order->user->name}}</h1>
</div>
```

the user table is a belongsto of orders

Controller:

```
public function sendMail(Order $order) {
        $order = $order->newQuery();
        
        $order->whereHas('user', function($query){
                $query->where('email', '=', \Auth::user()->email);
            });
            
        $order->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();    

        $user = User::where('email', '=', \Auth::user()->email)->first();
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new AfterOrder($order));


        //return redirect()->route('home')->with(['message' => 'Thank you for shopping at Sneakers!']);
    }
```

Whats wrong? i got this error

[image]

Comment: did you mean to capitalize `$this->Order` in the AfterOrder constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$order` is still a Builder object when you do this.

```php
$order->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

To get the actual Model, you need to do the following:

```php
$order = $order->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the solution. One more question, excuse me, why is the view's `$order->user->name` returning me null?

Comment: I'm not sure. Maybe its value is null or empty in the database. Have you tried eager-loading it by either calling `->with('user')` before `first()` or `$order->load('user')` in your mail constructor?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. The value that gives me null is the reference column of the Order table. In user it does not give me null because I get it directly from \Auth::user That is my code what return null `<h1>Order Reference: {{$order->reference}}</h1>`

Comment: I'm not sure if you still have that typo in your code but in your constructor it should be `$this->order` and not `$this->Order`. Also, have you checked if the reference is null in the database?